# python: invalid syntax on sys

Tags: python, sys

I am new to Python,
I tried to execute file with code:

```
import sys
def main():
    print sys.argv[1]

main()
```

For this run: hello.py from command line, but got

```
C:\Python34>hello.py
File "C:\Python34\hello.py", line 4
print sys.argv[1]
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Also, you need to indent the `print()`

Comment: When you run `python` what version does it show? e.g. `$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 12 2013, 21:33:34) `

Comment: @lukas: The traceback wasn't enough of a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3.4 requires <strike>brackets</strike> parentheses around prints.
E.g. print(sys.argv[1])

Comment: As a further point, it requires brackets around _all_ functions now. I made the same errors when transitioning from 2.7 too ^_^

Comment: `()` are called parentheses. Brackets are `[]`.

Comment: You're quite correct.

Comment: @milmulho Functions calls have always required parentheses. The difference between Python 2 and 3 is that `print` is no longer a statement, but a function.

Answer (score 5):

In Python 3.x `print` is no longer a statement, it is a function `print()`, and as suggested in PEP8, you should ident your code with 4 space per level.

```
import sys
def main():
    print(sys.argv[1])

main()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to insert a tab before "print sys.argv[1]"